# Are these two expression equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

My friend insisted that $(-1)^{(-n)}$ is equivalent to $(-1)^n$ for any number of $n$. A quick check in the `Wolfram Alpha` show `false` like this:

[image]

But then he showed me the working (substituting $n=0$ to $n=3$ in each expression)and indeed they are the same.

So, I am a bit confused on whether those two expressions are really equal. Will they give out the same number every time or am i missing something?

Comment: Consider 2 cases: when $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: Mathematica code:
Table[(-1)^(n), {n, 1, 12}] and
Table[(-1)^(-n), {n, 1, 12}] the difference is zero for all cases.

Comment: WolframAlpha does not automatically assume that $n$ is an integer.

Comment: It is simply that a number and its inverse have the same sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your friend and you both know that the expression $(-1)^x$ only makes sense if $x$ is an integer.

That said, you have

$$(-1)^{(-n)} = \frac{1}{(-1)^n} = \left(\frac{1}{-1}\right)^n = (-1)^n$$

I believe all steps only use equalities you learnt in school:

- For all $a, b$ we have $a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$
- If $\frac{c}{d}$ is a fraction, then $\left(\frac cd\right)^b = \frac{c^b}{d^b}$
- $\frac{a}{-b} = -\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the question in OP is to understand why WolframAlpha gives ''false'' as answer.

This is because WA evaluate the expressions $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{-n}$ in the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. In this case have, for $n=a+ib$ we have:
$$
(-1)^n=(e^{i\pi})^{a+ib}=e^{a \pi i}e^{-b \pi}
$$
$$
(-1)^{-n}=(e^{i\pi})^{-a-ib}=e^{-a \pi i}e^{b \pi}
$$
That are, in general, different.

If $n$ is a real positive number than, using Euler formula $ e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, we find:

$$
(-1)^{n}=(e^{i\pi})^n=\cos (\pi n)+i\sin(\pi n)
$$

$$
(-1)^{-n}=(e^{i\pi})^{-n}=\cos (-\pi n)+i\sin(-\pi n)=\cos (\pi n)-i\sin(\pi n)
$$ 
that are equal iff $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So the result for $n$ **integer** is that $(-1)^{n}=(-1)^{-n}$ and WA agree as you can see [here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5En%3D%28-1%29%5E%28-n%29%20%20)

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ (-1)^{-n} = \frac{1}{(-1)^n} = \frac{1^n}{(-1)^n} = \left(\frac{1}{(-1)}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1(-1)}{(-1)(-1)}\right)^n = (-1)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess that mathematica or whatever wolfram thing that gave you this answer was just confused by the definition of n. If it is *not* an integer, the equality fails. You can convince yourself of this by choosing n to be 1/2 (granted that you know about complex numbers).

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{(-1)^n}=(-1)^n \implies 1=(-1)^n(-1)^n \implies 1=(-1)^{2n}$
which is true for all integers, but nothing else.